# Replacing image in database with edit/update function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using **codeigniter** 3 So I have tried some of the examples here while searching for this issue. To no avail.

My problem is when I edit a post I am able to get all the input fields with data originally posted to display and edit accordingly. My issue is on the photo part, it uploads the image to the folder on the server, but the image name is not updated to the database so the view cannot display it.

(This issue is only on edit, on create the post it works perfect).

So what is it that I am missing here?

---

P.S.:: Also if someone can give me a tip on how to load the original uploaded image in the edit field so if the person decided to keep the original image they uploaded they would not need to re add it again.

---

My controller

```
public function edit($slug){
  $data['categories'] = $this->post_model->get_categories();
  $data['post_image'] = $this->post_model->get_posts('post_image');
  $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);
  if(empty($data['post'])){
    show_404();
  }
$data['title'] = 'Edit Your Post';
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('posts/edit', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
public function update(){
  if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                redirect('users/login');
            }
else{
  if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != "")
  {
     if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){
      $ext = ".jpeg";
    }
      if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/jpg'){
       $ext = ".jpg";
     }
      else if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/png'){
      $ext = ".png";
    }
}
    $imageedit = time();
            $config = array(
              'file_name' => $imageedit,
              'upload_path' => "assets/images/posts/",
              'allowed_types' => "jpg|png|jpeg",
            );
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
          $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error_msg', $this->upload->display_errors());
               redirect('posts/edit');
             }
             else {
      $this->post_model->update_post($imageedit);
      $imageedit = "assets/images/posts/".$imageedit;
    }
  $slug = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);
  $this->post_model->update_post();
  $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
  redirect('posts');
}
}
  }
```

The model

```
public function update_post($imageedit,$slug){

  $site = $this->input->post('site');


  $data = array(

  'title'=>$this->input->post('title'),
  //'slug'=>$slug,
  'body'=> $this->input->post('Description'),
  'post_image' => $imageedit,
  'Number'=> $this->input->post('Number'),
  "Languages"=>$this->input->post('Lang'),
  'site'=>$site

  );
  $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));
  return $this->db->update('posts',$data);
}

}

?>
```

Comment: What does this `$data['post_image']` gives you in edit function? Your Image array?

Comment: I was actually just trying to see if I was able to load the image that way from the model, its commented out in my code

Comment: please refer my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816648/replacing-image-in-database-with-edit-update-function/54817036#54817036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image name is not updating in the database because after the else part, you are making null update request.

```
$this->post_model->update_post(); //Here you are passing nothing in update function.
```

make changes as below. because you have update function like `public function update_post($imageedit,$slug)`

```
else
{
    $imageedit = "assets/images/posts/".$imageedit;
}
$slug = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);

$this->post_model->update_post($imageedit,$slug);  //Update this line.
```

At the time of edit, to display/load the original uploaded image, In your View you can do as below.

Suppose you are getting your all image data in as below in an edit function.

```
$data['post_image'] = $this->post_model->get_posts('post_image');
$this->load->view('posts/edit', $data);
```

Here, you are getting your Image data as an Array in **$data['post_image']** and you are passing those all data to view file.

Add below code in View file above Browse Image code. So user can see original Image.

```
<?php if( $this->uri->segment(2) == 'edit' ) { ?>
Your Original uploaded Image
<img src="assets/images/posts/<?php echo $post_image[0]['post_image']; ?>" title="Image" alt="Image" />
<?php } ?>
<br />
Upload New Image => 
<?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'file','name'=>'userfile','id'=>'userfile','accept'=>'.jpg,.jpeg,.png')); } ?>
```

**Note :-** Above is just example for how to display your original image at edit time in View file.  **Make sure you change your images path as per your requirement.**

**EDIT =>** At time of Edit View Part, I am displaying View as below Image. So user can see the Original Image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Two questions I have. One in my controller I have the create function to create a post. I use the same function for image upload as I do in function update, but in update I had to remove the line     $imageedit = "assets/images/posts/".$imageedit; Because it was saving the assets/images/posts in the database but it does not do that in the create function. Any Idea why?

Comment: Also I cannot seem to get your original upload function to work, as if I do not upload a new photo I get a error.

Comment: There is no need to store your image path `$imageedit = "assets/images/posts/".$imageedit;` in the database. Simply save the imagename after encrypting the image name. Only storing image-name helps very well and very convenient.

Comment: I am always storing just image-name in database like `image1.jpg`. Never storing path.

Comment: One last thing, if you have another tip, is when I do not upload a new photo in the edit it will throw a error. So I am wondering would auto filling the original image in the $imagedit variable correct this?

Comment: @PHPNoob Are you using this same function `public function update(){` for adding and updating image?

Comment: adding the image I have another function